# change sizingPolicy for htmlwidgets without recreating the widget

Tags: r, highcharts, htmlwidgets

I'm creating a set of widgets in r using highcharter and need to change the viewer.padding and browser.padding without having to manually adjust each of the saved widgets.  Is there a way to accomplish this without recreating the entire highchart widget?